# ¿Como almacenar en una variable el resultado de un sitio web con jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente link:
https://saldo1.multifacturas.com/saldo/TMH151201HI7.txt
Si ustedes lo visitan arroja solamente un número.
quiero almacenar ese número en una variable en JS
Trate de usar ajax con jquery así:

$.ajax({url: "https://saldo1.multifacturas.com/saldo/TMH151201HI7.txt", success: function(result){
$("#div1").html(result);
}});

pero el navegador me arroja el error:
GET https://saldo1.multifacturas.com/saldo/TMH151201HI7.txt net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Alguna idea de como poder lograrlo??

Comment: La primera URL y la segunda son distintas, la primera es http y la segunda es https. Si visitas la segunda desde el navegador te saldrá el mismo mensaje de error, y la causa dependerá de la configuración de seguridad del sitio web y de tu navegador.

Comment: Ya intente poner la primera con https pero es cuando me arroja el error y necesito saber otra forma de poder obtener el contenido arrojado que solo es un número

Comment: Intentaste con la url que solo tiene http? (y no https)

Comment: Lo intente las dos con https, solo me queda intentar las dos con http,